# Unable to evaluate the integral $\int \csc\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\csc\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) dx $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

**The Question**
$$\int \csc\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\csc\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) dx $$
**What I Tried-**

 I tried dividing both numerator and denominator by $\sin \pi/6$ but couldn't get too far, what I got after dividing and doing some simplification-
$$2\int \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - \sin 2x}dx \ = \int \csc\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+x\right)\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)dx$$
Now I am stuck after this step and don't think there is scope for simplification. Kindly tell where I am going wrong, it may be a very stupid mistake.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\csc (x + \pi/6) \csc (x - \pi/6)$?

Comment: You are asking it for the question or for my answer?

Comment: I have multiplied the integral by 2, it is one and the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

$$\csc(x-\pi/3)\csc(x-\pi/6)$$

$$=\dfrac1{\sin(\pi/3-\pi/6)}\cdot\dfrac{\sin(x-\pi/6-(x-\pi/3))}{\sin(x-\pi/3)\sin(x-\pi/6)}$$

Comment: I just figured that out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\csc \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)\csc \left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)= \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{6}-x\right) \sec \left(x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}-2 \sin (2x) }$$ Now, let $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$ and tou face
$$I=4\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{3} t^2-4 t+\sqrt{3}}$$ The denominator has two simple real roots. Then partial fraction decomposition to face two simple integrals.

Comment: How did you think that, that's nowhere near standard substitutions

Comment: @VyomYadav. This is just the tangent half-angle subsitution.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $t= \tan(x-\frac\pi4)$

$$\int \csc\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\csc\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) dx =4\int \frac{2-\sqrt3}{t^2-(2-\sqrt3)^2}dt\\
= 4\ln | \frac{2-\sqrt3-t}{2-\sqrt3+ t} |
= 4\ln | \frac{2-\sqrt3-\tan(x-\frac\pi4)}{2-\sqrt3+ \tan(x-\frac\pi4)} |+C
$$